# How to write this Query using LINQ in C#.net?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_scanxmlreports
WHERE Id_XmlMasterFile = (SELECT id 
                          FROM tbl_uploadfilereport
                          WHERE ProjectId=194);
```

Sorry to ask this easy question but i am totally new in LINQ.
Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

```
var scanXmlReportsByProjectId = (from sxr in tbl_scanxmlreports
                                 join ufr in tbl_uploadfilereport on sxr.Id_XmlMasterFile equals ufr.id
                                 where ufr.ProjectId == 194
                                 select sxr).ToList();
```

You have to `join` your both tables and filter it by your ID *194* (with the `where`). After that just `select` the result.

Please take a look in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/queries-in-linq-to-entities) too. It will be very helpful to create queries.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm correct its something like this:

```
var x = Id_XmlMasterfile.Where(a => a.ProjectId == 194).Select(id);
var result = tbl_scanxmlreports.Where(b => b.Id_XmlMasterfile == x);
```

but i guess there are more efficient ways

here is a good way to learn about querying in EF

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx